# Categorizing Values in a data.frame

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have the following sample data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(v=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d"))
> df
  v 
1 a 
2 a 
3 b 
4 b 
5 c 
6 d 
7 d
```

I would like to categorize these values in a separate column based on some arbitrary mapping.  For example:

- a -> x
- b -> x
- c -> y
- d -> y

So afterwards, I would have the following:

```
  v cat
1 a   x
2 a   x
3 b   x
4 b   x
5 c   y
6 d   y
7 d   y
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option:

create a named vector with the mapping:

```
x <- c(a = "x", b = "x", c = "y", d = "y")
```

Then add the new column using the named vector:

```
df$cat <- x[df$v]
df
#  v cat
#1 a   x
#2 a   x
#3 b   x
#4 b   x
#5 c   y
#6 d   y
#7 d   y
```

Comment: Thank you, what if the values in v are not valid identifiers (e.g. "e f")?

Comment: @oneself, Then adjust the named vector accordingly, for example `x <- c(a = "x", b = "x", c = "y", "e f" = "y")`

Comment: Thank you, last question: what happens if one of the values is missing?  Is there a way to specify a default?

Comment: @oneself, You can easily use an `ifelse` with it: `y <- x[df$v]; df$cat <- ifelse(is.na(y), "default", y)`. The other option is to use the code from my original answer and later replace all the NA entries (where there was no match).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using a `data.frame` where you write your mapping:

```
library(plyr)

mapping = data.frame(v=letters[1:4], cat=c("x","x","y","y"))

join(df, mapping, by='v')
#  v cat
#1 a   x
#2 a   x
#3 b   x
#4 b   x
#5 c   y
#6 d   y
#7 d   y
```

Or directly base `R`:

```
merge(df, mapping, by='v')
#  v cat
#1 a   x
#2 a   x
#3 b   x
#4 b   x
#5 c   y
#6 d   y
#7 d   y
```

Comment: I tend to use plyr when I work, hence more use of join than merge, just reflex ;)